# Внесение изменений в динамические библиотеки (Shared Libraries)

Tags: linux, c, ос

Предположим, у нас есть программа на языке C, которая использует динамическую библиотеку.

Если мы внесем изменения в динамическую библиотеку и перекомпилируем ее, все программы, использующие эту библиотеку, автоматически получат эти изменения при следующем запуске. В случае статической библиотеки изменения становятся заметны только после перекомпиляции программы с новой версией библиотеки.

Если мы изменим код некоторых функций динамической библиотеки (без изменения сигнатур функций), добавим новые функции и т. д., то адреса этих функций изменятся.

Как программа, использующая нашу динамическую библиотеку, сможет снова найти эти функции без перекомпиляции и перелинковки? Если их адреса изменились.

Comment: Они, грубо говоря, ищут функции не по адресу, а по имени/номеру.

Comment: @Harry то есть сама программа ищет?

Comment: Загрузчик. Но может и сама программа. Не знаю, как в Linux'е, но в Windows API есть функции загрузки DLL и получения адреса конкретной функции из нее.

Comment: [Тут описан весь процесс](https://amir.rachum.com/shared-libraries/) (и внизу масса ссылок на др. инфу)

Comment: (внезапно) адреса функций могут меняются и без перекомпиляции из-за Address Space Layout Randomization. А программа находит смещения функций по таблице экспорта в библиотеке.